# Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (3,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB9qc.png)
I am trying to train a model that will detect the native language of the speaker from the speech data which is already taken which will be in the English language.
 I got this error while I am trying to run the below code and it is unable to train the model.
What is the mistake anyone explain?
Below is the code snippet of the training model :

```
            import pandas as pd
            from collections import Counter
            import sys
            sys.path.append('../dialectdetect-master/src>')
            import getsplit


            from keras import utils
            import accuracy
            import multiprocessing
            import librosa
            import numpy as np
            from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
            from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

            from keras.models import Sequential
            from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
            from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D, Conv2D
            from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
            from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, TensorBoard

            DEBUG = True
            SILENCE_THRESHOLD = .01
            RATE = 24000
            N_MFCC = 13
            COL_SIZE = 30
            EPOCHS = 10 #35#250

            def to_categorical(y):
                '''
                Converts list of languages into a binary class matrix
                :param y (list): list of languages
                :return (numpy array): binary class matrix
                '''
                lang_dict = {}
                for index,language in enumerate(set(y)):
                    lang_dict[language] = index
                y = list(map(lambda x: lang_dict[x],y))
                return utils.to_categorical(y, len(lang_dict))

            def get_wav(language_num):
                '''
                Load wav file from disk and down-samples to RATE
                :param language_num (list): list of file names
                :return (numpy array): Down-sampled wav file
                '''

                y, sr = librosa.load('../audio/{}.wav'.format(language_num))
                return(librosa.core.resample(y=y,orig_sr=sr,target_sr=RATE, scale=True))

            def to_mfcc(wav):
                '''
                Converts wav file to Mel Frequency Ceptral Coefficients
                :param wav (numpy array): Wav form
                :return (2d numpy array: MFCC
                '''
                return(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=wav, sr=RATE, n_mfcc=N_MFCC))

            def remove_silence(wav, thresh=0.04, chunk=5000):
                '''
                Searches wav form for segments of silence. If wav form values are lower than 'thresh' for 'chunk' samples, the values will be removed
                :param wav (np array): Wav array to be filtered
                :return (np array): Wav array with silence removed
                '''

                tf_list = []
                for x in range(len(wav) / chunk):
                    if (np.any(wav[chunk * x:chunk * (x + 1)] >= thresh) or np.any(wav[chunk * x:chunk * (x + 1)] <= -thresh)):
                        tf_list.extend([True] * chunk)
                    else:
                        tf_list.extend([False] * chunk)

                tf_list.extend((len(wav) - len(tf_list)) * [False])
                return(wav[tf_list])

            def normalize_mfcc(mfcc):
                '''
                Normalize mfcc
                :param mfcc:
                :return:
                '''
                mms = MinMaxScaler()
                return(mms.fit_transform(np.abs(mfcc)))

            def make_segments(mfccs,labels):
                '''
                Makes segments of mfccs and attaches them to the labels
                :param mfccs: list of mfccs
                :param labels: list of labels
                :return (tuple): Segments with labels
                '''
                segments = []
                seg_labels = []
                for mfcc,label in zip(mfccs,labels):
                    for start in range(0, int(mfcc.shape[1] / COL_SIZE)):
                        segments.append(mfcc[:, start * COL_SIZE:(start + 1) * COL_SIZE])
                        seg_labels.append(label)
                return(segments, seg_labels)

            def segment_one(mfcc):
                '''
                Creates segments from on mfcc image. If last segments is not long enough to be length of columns divided by COL_SIZE
                :param mfcc (numpy array): MFCC array
                :return (numpy array): Segmented MFCC array
                '''
                segments = []
                for start in range(0, int(mfcc.shape[1] / COL_SIZE)):
                    segments.append(mfcc[:, start * COL_SIZE:(start + 1) * COL_SIZE])
                return(np.array(segments))

            def create_segmented_mfccs(X_train):
                '''
                Creates segmented MFCCs from X_train
                :param X_train: list of MFCCs
                :return: segmented mfccs
                '''
                segmented_mfccs = []
                for mfcc in X_train:
                    segmented_mfccs.append(segment_one(mfcc))
                return(segmented_mfccs)


            def train_model(X_train,y_train,X_validation,y_validation, batch_size=128): #64
                '''
                Trains 2D convolutional neural network
                :param X_train: Numpy array of mfccs
                :param y_train: Binary matrix based on labels
                :return: Trained model
                '''

                # Get row, column, and class sizes
                rows = X_train[0].shape[0]
                cols = X_train[0].shape[1]
                val_rows = X_validation[0].shape[0]
                val_cols = X_validation[0].shape[1]
                num_classes = len(y_train[0])

                # input image dimensions to feed into 2D ConvNet Input layer
                input_shape = (rows, cols, 1)
                X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], rows, cols, 1 )
                X_validation = X_validation.reshape(X_validation.shape[0],val_rows,val_cols,1)


                print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
                print(X_train.shape[0], 'training samples')

                model = Sequential()

                model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu',
                                 data_format="channels_last",
                                 input_shape=input_shape))

                model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
                model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
                model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
                model.add(Dropout(0.25))

                model.add(Flatten())
                model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
                model.add(Dropout(0.5))

                model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
                model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                              optimizer='adadelta',
                              metrics=['accuracy'])

                # Stops training if accuracy does not change at least 0.005 over 10 epochs
                es = EarlyStopping(monitor='acc', min_delta=.005, patience=10, verbose=1, mode='auto')

                # Creates log file for graphical interpretation using TensorBoard
                tb = TensorBoard(log_dir='..\logs', histogram_freq=0, batch_size=32, write_graph=True, write_grads=True,
                                 write_images=True, embeddings_freq=0, embeddings_layer_names=None,
                                 embeddings_metadata=None)

                # Image shifting
                datagen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.05)

                # Fit model using ImageDataGenerator
                model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
                                    steps_per_epoch=len(X_train) / 32
                                    , epochs=EPOCHS,
                                    callbacks=[es,tb], validation_data=(X_validation,y_validation))

                return (model)

            def save_model(model, model_filename):
                '''
                Save model to file
                :param model: Trained model to be saved
                :param model_filename: Filename
                :return: None
                '''
                model.save('../models/{}.h5'.format(model_filename))  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'



            ############################################################




            #######################################

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                '''
                    Console command example:
                    python trainmodel.py bio_metadata.csv model50
                    '''

                # Load arguments
                # print(sys.argv)
                file_name = sys.argv[1]
                model_filename = sys.argv[2]

                # Load metadata
                df = pd.read_csv(file_name)


                # Filter metadata to retrieve only files desired
                filtered_df = getsplit.filter_df(df)

                # filtered_df = filter_df(df)

                # print(filtered_df)

                # print("filterd df is empty {}".format(filtered_df))

                # Train test split
                X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = getsplit.split_people(filtered_df)

                # Get statistics
                train_count = Counter(y_train)
                test_count = Counter(y_test)
                print("Entering main")

                # import ipdb;
                # ipdb.set_trace()


                acc_to_beat = test_count.most_common(1)[0][1] / float(np.sum(list(test_count.values())))

                # To categorical
                y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
                y_test = to_categorical(y_test)

                # Get resampled wav files using multiprocessing
                if DEBUG:
                    print('Loading wav files....')
                pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
                X_train = pool.map(get_wav, X_train)
                X_test = pool.map(get_wav, X_test)

                # Convert to MFCC
                if DEBUG:
                    print('Converting to MFCC....')
                X_train = pool.map(to_mfcc, X_train)
                X_test = pool.map(to_mfcc, X_test)


                # Create segments from MFCCs
                X_train, y_train = make_segments(X_train, y_train)
                X_validation, y_validation = make_segments(X_test, y_test)

                # Randomize training segments
                X_train, _, y_train, _ = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=50)
                # Train model
                model = train_model(np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train), np.array(X_validation),np.array(y_validation))

                # Make predictions on full X_test MFCCs
                y_predicted = accuracy.predict_class_all(create_segmented_mfccs(X_test), model)

                # Print statistics
                print('Training samples:', train_count)
                print('Testing samples:', test_count)
                print('Accuracy to beat:', acc_to_beat)
                print('Confusion matrix of total samples:\n', np.sum(accuracy.confusion_matrix(y_predicted, y_test),axis=1))
                print('Confusion matrix:\n',accuracy.confusion_matrix(y_predicted, y_test))
                print('Accuracy:', accuracy.get_accuracy(y_predicted,y_test))

                # Save model
                save_model(model, model_filename)
```

Comment: Are the values in `y_train[0]` unique?

Comment: Try to debug and find a specific piece of code which is giving the error rather than posting the whole script.

Comment: @ShanikaEdiriweera i have edited the post at the beginning of the post i have uploaded the picture of the error

Comment: @emremrah Yes the y_train[0] is unique and its value is 6